# How to continuous delivery with Database SSDT c# VSTS EF6 Azure

Tags: c#, database, azure-devops, sql-server-data-tools, continuous-delivery

I want to implement CI and CD for website with database (on Azure).

Tools:

- SSDT (project database)
- C#
- VSTS (Visual studio team services)
- EF6 (entity framework 6)
- Azure SQL database

**The aim is a full Continuous Delivery even with the database (Hardest part).
For the website, CD is pretty much easy with VSTS. But about the database, I can't find a clear way how to proceed.
So by some readings I plan to** :

1. Use SSDT to manage the Database. VSTS build, use dacpac of the database projet to generate by itself by schema comparison to update the database. I'll just write sql script for data motion.
2. Use EF6 and "reverse POCO code first generator" [link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SimonHughes.EntityFrameworkReversePOCOGenerator)

To be 100% Continuous Delivery, I can't stop the service, even during database schema modification.

So I read that database update has to be compatible with previous deploiement (DAL of running website). So all database schema modification will be in to 2 steps, in two deliveries. The Second delivery can be only when the 1 step is delivered.

So rules should be

1. Rename a table is not allowed
2. Rename a column is not allowed
3. Add column
   1 Step

   - Add column in SSDT with default value
   - Add property to entity class 
     2 Step
   - Remove default value on the database
4. Remove column
   1 Step

   - Remove column on entity
   - Add default value by SSDT
     2 Step
   - Remove column by SSDT

I'm pretty sur, that I'm reinventing the wheel, but I can't find a complet tutorial.
Am I on the good way ? Is there something out the box solution in microsoft world ? I'm ready to learn. Thank you

Comment: Good question, I'm trying to figure this one out myself. The solution seems to involve mirroring the databases and performing a fail-over to a mirror during the deployment, then failing back to your upgraded database and letting the new schema changes replicate over. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/transactional/peer-to-peer-transactional-replication

Comment: @s3raph86 Check this:https://dzone.com/articles/zero-downtime-deployment-with-a-database-1

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy database to azure through Azure SQL Database Deployment step/task in you build or release. Also, you can deploy your app to Azure through VSTS Build or release.

For example:

1. Add an [Azure Resource Manager](https://github.com/geeklearningio/gl-vsts-tasks-azure/wiki/How-to-Setup-an-Azure-Resource-Manager-Endpoint)
2. Create a build definition on your VSTS
3. Add Visual Studio Build step to build database project and it will generate dacpac file.
4. Add Azure SQL Database Deployment step to deploy database to azure via dacpac file (step 3)
5. Add Visual Studio Build step to build your app project
6. (optional) Add Azure App Service Deploy step to deploy your app (web) if needed.
7. (optional) Go to trigger and check Continuous integration (CI) to queue build for each check-in

[There](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ssdt/2016/04/06/sqldb-cicd-part1-prereq/) is a related article (follow up its workflow, it uses Azure Classic, you could use Azure Resource Manager).

Comment: Yes, but how do you avoid zero downtime database ? The second part of my question.

Comment: @Julian50 You can deploy to a new database, then change config file to point to the new database.